# Linux version check Linux command or a Java code

Tags: java, linux, shell, command, version

I want to check whether the currently installed RHEL version is greater that RHEL 6.

All I find is lots linux commands to get the RHEL version.
Some check files from /etc folder, some do RPM checks.

So I am bit confuse now and want something Rigid which will work even if version of OS changes later.

Please suggest me a way. Either Linux command or a Java code. Anything will do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with?

```
cat /etc/*-release
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

or

```
cat /etc/issue
```

or

```
cat /proc/version
```

or even with

```
uname -a
```

Looking at Java documentation I see you can get few basic information about the operating system via [System.getProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html), I suppose you use Java Standard Edition 6.0. But very likely also other versions should return same infos.

- os.name   Operating system name
- os.arch   Operating system architecture
- os.version    Operating system version

Answer (score 2):

OS version:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4 (Nahant Update 5)
```

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux islamabad.bdnacn.com 2.6.9-55.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Apr 20 17:03:35 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Both of them will change if OS gets upgrade.